# Comparing lists with numpy floats vs. regular floats

Tags: python

Given the following code:

```
def to_l(pos_probs, threshold):
    return (pos_probs >= threshold).astype('int')

thresh = np.arange(0, 0.2, 0.1)
print(thresh)
```

This works:

```
print([to_l([0.2,0.3], w) for w in thresh])
```

Result:

```
[0.  0.1]
[array([1, 1]), array([1, 1])]
```

But this doesn't:

```
[to_l([0.2,0.3], w) for w in [0.,0.1]]
```

And this doesn't:

```
to_l([0.2,0.3], 0.1)
```

Giving the error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

The type error is clear in the second and third situation. We are comparing a list [0.2,0.3] to a float 0.1.
But would someone explain why it DOES work in the first situation?

Comment: Because `thresh` is a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: this really has nothing to do with list comprehensions, it's a question about numpy

Comment: Yes. I will remove that from the title.

Comment: This works ```[to_l([0.2,0.3], w) for w in np.array([0.,0.1])]``` . Also ```[([0.2,0.3], w) for w in np.array([0.,0.1])]``` gives the same result as ```[([0.2,0.3], w) for w in [0.,0.1]]```. Yet, ```[to_l([0.2,0.3], w) for w in [0.,0.1]]``` doesn't work.

Comment: I will read more on the ```numpy.ndarray```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called broadcasting which is supported by numpy. So when two operands in the operation are of different shapes, numpy will try to broadcast it and do the operation.

- `[0.2,0.3] >= 0` will not work because numpy is not involved here. You will get the error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

- `np.array([1, 2, 3]) > 2` will work as numpy broadcasting will come into picture.
- `[1, 2, 3] > np.float32(2)` will also work

However,

- `[1, 2, 3] > np.float(2)` will not work because `np.float` is just an alias to python `float`. But `np.float32` and `np.float64` are np implementations of single and double precision number respectively.

Comment: Thanks. Also this type conversion ```(np.array([1, 2, 3]) > 2).astype('int') ``` (part of the to_l() method above) works for the same reason you mentioned while ```([1, 2, 3]) > 2).astype('int')``` doesn't since lists cannot be converted to ints.